# Probability of a statement being true using a different sampling density from the probability density

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, monte-carlo

Suppose that, given a vector of parameters $\mathbf{x}$, we know the conditional probability of some statement $S$ being true, $P(S|\mathbf{x})$. However, $\mathbf{x}$ itself is a random variable with probability density $\rho(\mathbf{x})$. Then it seems reasonable (to me) that the probability of $S$ given the probability density $\rho$ is
$$
  P(S|\rho) = \int_\Omega P(S|\mathbf{x}) \, \rho(\mathbf{x}) \, d{\mathbf{x}}
$$
where $\Omega = \operatorname{supp} \rho$. However, if $P(S|\mathbf{x})$ is only known numerically then we may wish to sample $N$ values of $\mathbf{x}$ and compute the average from the samples. Denote the probability density of $\mathbf{x}$ being a sample point by $\mu(\mathbf{x})$, where $\operatorname{supp} \mu \supseteq \Omega$, then it seems reasonable (to me) that
$$
  P(S|\rho) = \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N P(S|\mathbf{x}_n) \, \frac{\rho(\mathbf{x}_n)}{\mu(\mathbf{x}_n)}
$$
where $\mathbf{x}_n$ is the sample. Then an approximation can be found by using some large but finite $N$, I suppose this would be a 'Monte Carlo' approach.

Above I have said the phrase 'it seems reasonable (to me)' before each of the display equations. I have two questions:

1. Are these equations correct?
2. How would they be proved?

I think the first of the equations should be straightforward from the definition of probability densities, but I can't see it yet. The second I'm not sure how I would prove, but some alteration to the notation will be needed to account for the 'almost surely' nature of the convergence. Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: What does *$P(S|x)$ is only known numerically* mean? You claim that we know $P(S|x)$ in the opening sentence, which would (I think, if I understood correctly) imply that we can compute $f(X)=P(S|X)$ (i.e. we know $f$).

Comment: I mean that we have an algorithm to compute the function, which can be run on a computer to deduce the value for a given value of x. However, the function may be computationally expensive, say >1 min for an evaluation.